# Installing Cloud9 on Ubuntu not using github

Tags: ubuntu, github, cloud9-ide

All installations of Cloud9 I could find use github. Unfortunately in my company ports used by github are blocked.

Is there a way to install Cloud9 without using github?

Thanks.

Comment: You could install it on another computer then copy that folder and ~/.c9 folder

Answer (score 1):

If you can't clone the repo with git because TCP port 9418 is closed, any repo on Github can also be downloaded as a zip file via http, and then unzipped.

Look for the "Download ZIP" button on Github, or, for the 'core' repo belonging to 'c9' construct a link like this:

```
https://github.com/c9/core/archive/master.zip
```

Comment: Thank you for great suggestions.